# CORS headers not on response when hitting endpoint from PostMan

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cors, .net-5

I have a ASP.net Web API that is using .NET 5

I am trying to configure CORS using the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

From what I understand in the documentation I don't need to add anything onto my controller as this should configure CORS globally. The controller is inheriting from Controller

When I hit my endpoint in PostMan I do not get any CORS headers coming back. Spent a good few days trying to troubleshoot this one so any help is appreciated.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "defaultPolicy",
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                                         .WithHeaders("Content-Type", "Accept", "Referer", "Authorization", "Sec-Fetch-Mode", "User-Agent");
                              });
        });

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

        services.AddTransient<IModelRepository, ModelRepository>();

        services.AddTransient<IModelService, ModelService>();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "RecommendationsAPI", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "RecommendationsAPI v1"));
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("defaultPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

PostMan request and response
[image]

Comment: postman will not hit cors generally. the browser is a good place to see what actually happens.

Comment: Add Origin header to request at least, without it the concept of CORS doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not sure if this help but you can try builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) instead of builder.AllowAnyOrigin()

Comment: @DanielA.White Still not coming through on browser unfortunately. Just deployed the project to an app service but still no luck

Comment: @Evk on endpoints on .Net framework projects I am able to get CORS headers on the response with out sending them in the request. Assumed this would be similar. Just given it a go and still unable to get the headers property through on the response

Comment: @LevananGan Thanks for the suggestion, just tried this but still no luck :(